# How To use Php session variable as Angular Js Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('TodoApp', []);

app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.todos = ['test'];

  $scope.done = function(todo){
          var indexOf = $scope.todos.indexOf(todo);
          if (indexOf !== -1) {
              $scope.todos.splice(indexOf, 1);
          }
  };

  $scope.add = function() {
          $scope.todos.push($scope.newTodo);
          $scope.newTodo= '';
  };

});
```

I am new to angularjs and writing a simple todo list. I want the the data in $scope.todos to be dynamic so whenever a user moves to another page of my site and returns back he will get the same todos he has entered before. I am thinking of using PHP's session varible to store data into it and pass it to the angular app but I don't know how to do it or maybe this logic is not proper.I am new tho this so any new ideas to this would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can use `cookie` or `local storage` to store the user's todo list

   - cookie max size is small, but enough if you don't have too many todo
   - local storage max  size is 5mb. you can try this angular lib https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage
2. when use php session.if you don't want to make an extra ajax call, you have to echo the value in the page.

make the todo list a global var by echo the json in your php file.

`var g_todos = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['todo'] ?>;`

in your controller

```
if(typeof g_todos === 'object' && g_todos.length){
    $scope.todos = g_todos;
}else{
    $scope.todos = [];
}
```

I think use cookie or localstorage is better, the second method is quite ugly....